# My if statements don't seem to work. Might be an alternate way?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

So, the basic gist of this is that I run a report once an hour and I need it to fill the results into specific cells depending on what time of day it is. Right now I'm using if statements to tell it which fields to fill, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. I definitely run it every hour so the code doesn't have to be based on what time of day it is as long as it doesn't overwrite or delete what is already there and will move to the next row each time it's run. I've just included the top of my code as well as one instance of the if statements. After the first one I copied and pasted throughout the rest changing the variables as needed. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a better way to do this!

```
Sub Update()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Booking Window Avai -working copy.xlsm"
Dim currentWb As Workbook
Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim openWb As Workbook
Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

Dim openWs As Worksheet
Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Mail Format")
Dim rng_data As Range


Set rng_data = openWs.Range("B17")

If ("C2") = "" And Now() > ("09:00") And Now() < ("10:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C2").PasteSpecial          xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C3") = "" And Now() > ("10:00") And Now() < ("11:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C4") = "" And Now() > ("11:00") And Now() < ("12:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C5") = "" And Now() > ("12:00") And Now() < ("13:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C6") = "" And Now() > ("13:00") And Now() < ("14:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C7") = "" And Now() > ("14:00") And Now() < ("15:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C8") = "" And Now() > ("15:00") And Now() < ("16:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C9") = "" And Now() > ("16:00") And Now() < ("17:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]

End If
```

Comment: So, the value in `'[Booking Window Avai -working copy.xlsm]Mail Format'!$B$17` should be pasted into the correct row in column C of `Sheet1` in ThisWorkbook?  Does a column in `Sheet1` contain the time range?  Will be better to look for the correct time to paste to rather that lots of _If the time is 9:00 on every other Tuesday then paste to cell C3... If it's 9:01 then paste to another cell...etc, etc_

Comment: Also keep in mind that you're trying to paste into a sheet called `sht` not `Sheet1` - `currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C2").PasteSpecial` and that you're trying to use `PasteSpecial` as a destination for copy which can only be done on a direct Copy/Paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the time values in a column on `Sheet1` it will be much easier to move the values across.  This assumes that column B contains time values - `09:00`, `10:00`, etc.

```
Sub Update()

    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Dim rng_data As Range
    Dim sht_Target As Worksheet
    Dim lPasteRow As Long

    Set sht_Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Booking Window Avai -working copy.xlsm")
    Set rng_data = openWb.Worksheets("Mail Format").Range("B17")

    'This next row replaces your IF statements.
    lPasteRow = Application.Match(CDbl(Time()), sht_Target.Range("B:B"), 1)
    sht_Target.Cells(lPasteRow, 3) = rng_data.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I do actually have time values in column A. So I took your code and changed it to  
lPasteRow = Application.Match(CDbl(Time()),sht_Target.Range("A:A"), 1)
 sht_Target.Cells(lPasteRow, 3) = rng_data.Value    

Now it's erroring with Object Required on the first line. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I haven't had to work with time very often in VBA. Column A is just 9:00AM, 10:00AM etc. if that helps.

Comment: _it's erroring with Object Required on the first line_ :  You mean on the `Set sht_Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` line? Are the times in column A being treated as text or times by Excel - to find out you can enter `=A1*1` in a cell.  If it returns the time it's good, if it returns #VALUE you've got text (put a space before `AM` to turn to real time - `9:00 AM` rather than `9:00AM`.

Comment: Got it all fixed. Thank you for all your help, it all works great now and the code is so much cleaner!

Comment: It's `lPasteRow` I put a lower case `L` at the front so I know it's a Long.  But that wouldn't cause the error - you can't have a variable starting with a number, so it would be a syntax error and won't compile.

Comment: Good stuff.  What was the problem?  And please don't have solved it with `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: I had just totally missed the line where you Dim the pasterow. Monday morning brain. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

The `Now() < ("15:00")` does not do what your code expects. Take a look at the code below:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print Now()                               '09.04.2018 14:23:56
    Debug.Print Now() < ("10:00")                   'True
    Debug.Print Now() < ("something meaningless")   'True
    Debug.Print Now() < ("")                        'False

                                                    'This is one way to do it--v
    Debug.Print TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now), Second(Now)) < TimeSerial(10, 10, 0)

End Sub
```

As you see, you have to compare Values parsed to `Date` with Values parsed to `Date`. Otherwise it parses the date to a `String` and compares the strings.

`TimeSerial` is just one of the options. [TimeSerial MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/timeserial-function).